# Checking the status of prefork in Apache

Tags: apache-2.4

It seems that prefork module is loaded, but the server MPM is empty.

```
# apache2ctl -M | grep prefork
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
# apache2 -V | grep MPM
Server MPM:
```

Also, there is no library file for that.

```
# find /etc/apache2/ -name mod_mpm_prefork.so
#
```

and the content of `mpm_prefork.conf` is

```
# cat /etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
        StartServers                     5
        MinSpareServers           5
        MaxSpareServers          10
        MaxRequestWorkers         150
        MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

So, am I using prefork module or not?

Answer (score 1):

Module location is: `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so`

Show loaded modules: `sudo apache2ctl -M`

Show mpm type: `apachectl -V`

Disable event/worker they will conflict with prefork

Disable: `sudo a2dismod mpm_event & sudo a2dismod mpm_worker`

Enable: `sudo a2enmod mpm_prefork`

Check Apache status with: `sudo service apache2 status`

Answer (score 0):

When you run `apache2 -V` you are not running a server - it doesn't load any modules.

> So, am I using prefork module or not?

It depends how the hhtpd is configured (and no - not just the config files - how it was compiled, what modules are loaded on what order at runtime). Set up mod_status to see how your **server** is behaving.